# "restart" app if no internet connection

Tags: java, android, webview

I am building a webview where if there is no internet connection, it will load a local error html file. I made it work in my **MainActivity** which is where the webview is created. But I am having a problem accessing my webview from **ourViewClient** that handles all the stuff happening inside the webview. So i cannot use the `browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");` inside that class. I tried using intent but absolutely nothing happens when i press a button on my web page when i have no internet connection. Is there a possibility of replacing the intent with a command which kinda restarts the app and start from the beginning so it checks for internet connection in the MainActivity again? I am a beginner at this so please explain simple

This is the intent that does not work in **ourViewClient**

```
if (CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(context)) {
    return false;
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/error.html"));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mClass = new ourViewClient(this);

    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvwMain);

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    browser.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient(this));
    if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)){
        browser.loadUrl("http://MyWebPage");
    } else {
        browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run a timer which will check if Internet connection is available or not after a certain period.

Example:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Check internet connection here
    }

},
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//check once every 10 seconds, you might want to do this less frequently as checking network  is a costly operation
10000);
```

And to restart your Activity do something like this.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    recreate(); //This method is only available on Android version 11 and above
} else {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I get errors using getIntent(), finish();, overridePendingTransition and overridePendingTransition - Cant resolve method

Comment: Where are you trying to use those methods? Are you using it in a class which extends Activity or something else? If you are using it outside of Activity class then you will have to use Activity's "Context" like this context.getIntent(), context.finish() and context.overridePendingTransition()